# how to enable VSCode insert newline setting, except not for Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: visual-studio-code

System: MacOSX Sonoma
VSCode: 1.83.1

The "insert final newline" setting in VSCode also inserts a newline at the end of every Jupyter Notebook cell.  Is there a way to disable this behavior only for Jupyter Notebook cells?

Comment: no you can't https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/35350

Comment: Or maybe you can https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1587

Comment: Try https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings if that works

Comment: @Dimava [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview) is orthogonal to [editor type](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors). What _exactly_ are you suggesting? there's no "Notebook" language mode because "Notebook" is an editor type and not a language mode.